# Trying to create a ticket using freshdesk API in postman

Tags: api, logout, postman, freshdesk

I am trying to create a ticket using the freshdesk api (https://freshdesk.com/api#create_ticket) in Postman.

I have used the following: https://companyname.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.json

```
{ "helpdesk_ticket": 
  { "description": "Details about the issue..."
  , "subject": "Support Needed..."
  , "email": "tom@outerspace.com"
  , "priority": 1
  , "status": 2 
  }
, "cc_emails": "ram@freshdesk.com,diana@freshdesk.com" 
}
```

I am getting following response only:

```
{
    "logout": "success"
}
```

I have tried clearing my browser cache many times. But the issue remains the same. Please someone suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This must be a bug at the time the question is raised.

Now the API has been updated and it works smoothly, your endpoint should be https://yoururl.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets with Authorization Token in the header

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same issues But When
I create the ssl login and check from curl then it works for me.